# How do I pass arguments from a one model's show page to another model's create controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have user, game and player models, and in my game's show page I am trying to create a player that will associate with both the current user and the game.

So I am on the page `blah.com/game/1` (show page for the game with id 1) and want to press a button to create a player.

In my Game's Show page:

```
  # I have @game here which is a reference to the game for this page
  # can I use it here to fill in @player.game ?
  <%= form_for(@player) do |f| %>
      <%= f.submit "Create player for this game (join this game)" %>
  <% end %>
```

Then, in my PlayerController's create method:

```
  # PlayerController's create, called from Game's show page
  def create
    @terra_player = current_user.players.build() # approximation of how it works
    if @terra_player.save
      redirect_to @terra_player
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

I believe I need to fill in the argument for the game manually, but I am unsure how to get a reference to the game that I have. I imagine I'd need to fill in the argument in the create controller:

```
  @terra_player = current_user.players.build(:game => ???) # approximation of how it works
```

Or else set it in the show page. But I am unsure how in either case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your models are kind of screwy here; I'd say you need to clean up your semantics.  Just taking a stab here, but my guess is that its a better bet to approach this with the idea that players are more closely connected to games than users.  Your models should probably look something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
  has_many :games, :through => :players
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
  validate :max_players_in_game #left as exercise to reader
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :game
end
```

Then in your routes, you'll have a nested resource for the game:

```
resources :games do
  resources :players
end
```

so your urls will look something like this: `POST /games/1/players`.  In your PlayersController:

```
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @game = Game.find(params[:game_id])
    @player = @game.players.build(:user => current_user)
    if @player.save
      redirect_to @game
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that is almost precisely how my classes are set up but and game-focus instead of user-focus is a very good point. But the problem I'm having in the first place is that I don't know how to get :game_id to be valid in `def create`. It doesn't seem to be, as is (neither does :id for that matter)

Comment: You're probably missing the nested routes portion of the setup.  with a nested route set as described above, your params hash will have a :game_id set (which comes from /games/:game_id/players).

Comment: if you're new to rails you may not realize this, but running `rake routes` at the console will spit out all of the routes you've got set up, and each route will give you some details about what controller/method will be called and what params you can expect to be set for each route.

Answer (score 0):

A creepy way would be

```
MyController.new.create_method parameters
```

I suggest not doing this. :-)